# Cannot deselect HTML 5 Range Slider Input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

I am not sure if this is a bug in Chrome but for some reason when I use a html 5 range input I cannot deselect it. Even when I move my cursor away and let go of the button on mouse the slider continues to follow mouse movement and I cannot set the slider value. Even if I tab to the next input I still have this issue
This example is from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range). I tried it on my android device and I don't have this same issue. Is there any workarounds, I specifically need to ensure it works with Angularjs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
Points: 0<input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">10
<input type="submit">
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> type="range" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: tried it on chrome and working fine for me, passing through points value and everything. :o

Comment: I'm using chrome 34 on windows 7, I have restarted Chrome. not sure why restarting my machine would affect it though but I will try

Comment: @ılǝ Restarting the machine has made no difference

Comment: I have tracked it back to an extension, If I disable all extensions and run an incognito tab it behaves as it should. I will gradually enable my extension until I track down the culprit and post results here

Comment: @jonnieM good thinking! When you track it down - you may want to include the name of the extension so that it's easier for others with similar issue to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Behaviour was as result of a Chrome Extension [Dictionary Bubble: Instant Dictionary](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfembjnmeainjncdflaoclcjadfhpoim), Once I disabled it the Slider functioned as expected

Comment: The reported issue was identified and has been fixed in version 3.28 of [Dictionary Bubble](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dictionary-bubble-instant/mfembjnmeainjncdflaoclcjadfhpoim).

Comment: Thats Great @ShahmeetSingh, update is much appreciated